# Have an instance method replace a static method

Tags: java

So I was working on a Base class,
And in that class I have some methods that could eventually be replaced with a factory. So I was wondering, I cannot, for example, make a static and a non-static method with the same name; the static one returning the object returned by `factory.build();` and the non-static one just returning `this` but with a few changes in the variable.

Is there any way I could do this? As far as I'm aware programmers should access static methods like `Class.method()` and instance methods by `instance.method()`

I could write my own addition to the compiler. But I was wondering if someone already did this.

And else wise is there anything I didn't realize why this isn't working?

Comment: where does the desire to have a static and an instance method with the same name (and presumably do the same) come from?

Comment: Typically your `static` method would have the same name but a different signature.  Since it would want to take in an instance of the class.  So `public ClassType method() { return this; }` and `public static ClassType method(final ClassType instance) { return instance; }`.  This is perfectly fine.